# Gevent. Парсинг заранее неизвестного количества страниц

Tags: python, асинхронность, синтаксический-анализ

Решил освоиться в gevent во время написания парсера, и все с ним хорошо, кроме одной проблемы: исходя из документации, нам заранее нужно знать, сколько страниц мы будем парсить:

```
for i in range(1, 15):
    handlers_group.add(gevent.spawn(handler, i))
handlers_group.join()
```

При этом обработчик может выглядеть так:

```
def handler(page_num):
    r = requests.get('sait.com?page={}'.format(page_num))
    if r.text != 'page not found':
        # последующие действия с данными
```

Как быть в случае, если мы не можем заранее знать количество страниц, по которым на нам нужно пройтись? Остановиться следует только тогда, когда ответ равен 'page not found'. Знаем только, что страниц обычно бывает от 15-ти до 50-ти и в редких случаях превышает сотню (крайнего предела не знаем, может встретится и миллион, но обрабатывать больше двух-трех сотен не имеет смысла).

Самое банальное, что приходит в голову, - создать запросы к 300-м страницам:

```
for i in range(1, 300):
    handlers_group.add(gevent.spawn(handler, i))
handlers_group.join()
```

и убить группу `handlers_group` из функции handler, когда ответ от сервера будет равным 'page not found'. Но в этом случае из-за асинхронности ответ от страницы №300 (которой, допустим, нет) может прийти раньше, чем от №250 (которая, допустим, существует), и мы убьем обработку страниц слишком рано, лишившись части информации.
Очень надеюсь на помощь сообщества в любом направлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, тут можно использовать `Queue` вместо `Group`. Суть в том, чтобы запустить N-воркров, скачивающих страницы по порядку из очереди. И первым встретившим "page not found" очищать оставшиеся элементы в очереди. Тогда все предыдущие воркеры благополучно завершат свою работу. Пример:

```
import gevent
import random
from gevent.queue import Queue

tasks = Queue(items=range(300))

def request_get(page_num):
    # simulate get request
    delay = random.random() * 3
    gevent.sleep(delay)

    if page_num > 37:
        return 'page not found'
    return 'page {}'.format(page_num)

def handler():
    while not tasks.empty():
        page_num = tasks.get()
        result = request_get(page_num)
        print('{}: {}'.format(page_num, result))

        if result == 'page not found':
            tasks.queue.clear()

# run 15 workers           
gevent.joinall([gevent.spawn(handler) for x in range(15)])
```

Результат:

```
2: page 2
12: page 12
9: page 9
6: page 6
11: page 11
17: page 17
14: page 14
5: page 5
21: page 21
15: page 15
1: page 1
0: page 0
13: page 13
20: page 20
7: page 7
4: page 4
16: page 16
23: page 23
22: page 22
18: page 18
27: page 27
25: page 25
3: page 3
24: page 24
8: page 8
10: page 10
36: page 36
40: page not found
19: page 19
29: page 29
41: page not found
35: page 35
30: page 30
26: page 26
39: page not found
38: page not found
31: page 31
28: page 28
32: page 32
34: page 34
37: page 37
33: page 33
```

Comment: Этот способ лучше моего, и лучше тем, что не приходится делать плохие вещи по типу gevent.sleep(), чтобы обработчик не натыкался на пустую очередь. Спасибо большое за решение!

Comment: Есть ли причины, по которым нужно самому Pool реализовывать, вместо использования готового, как в [моём ответе](http://hashcode.ru/questions/391654#391682)?

Comment: @jfs, изначально ваше ответ был без части "Вот полный пример:" и я, из-за не очень хорошего знания python, не понял что с ним делать. В этом ответе я разобрался и он мне помог.

Comment: @fogipoziw: если ответ неясен, то можно в комментарии задать вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве нулевого приближения можно написать код, который запрашивает только одну страницу за раз, например:

```
import itertools

for page_num in itertools.count(1):
    page, error = fetch_page(page_num)
    if error: # failed to fetch the page
        break
    # use `page` here...
```

где `fetch_page()` пытается загрузить `page_num`, используя обычную блокирующую сетевую библиотеку, и возвращает ошибку в случае неудачи.

Следущий шаг -- несколько запросов одновременно, используя потоки:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # thread pool

for page, error in Pool(20).imap(fetch_page, itertools.count(1)):
    if error: # failed to fetch the page
        break
    # use `page` here...
```

где `fetch_page()` функция осталась без изменений.

Следующий шаг -- попробовать выполнять одновременные запросы в одном потоке с помощью `gevent`. Можно попробовать добавить сверху модуля:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

# ... multiprocessing code example as is
```

и посмотреть, сломает ли это `multiprocessing`. Можно специализированный gevent Pool с похожим интерфейсом использовать, если `multprocessing` не работает в данном случае.

Вот полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import random
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # thread pool

def fetch_page(page_num):
    # simulate get request
    delay = random.random() * 3
    time.sleep(delay)

    if page_num > 37:
        return None, 'page not found'
    return 'page {}'.format(page_num), None

start = time.time()
for page, error in Pool(20).imap(fetch_page, xrange(100), chunksize=1):
    if error: # failed to fetch the page
        break
    print "%.2f %s" % (time.time() - start, page)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

#### Пример

```
$ time python fetch_urls.py
0.03 page 0
1.22 page 1
1.64 page 2
2.63 page 3
2.63 page 4
2.63 page 5
2.63 page 6
2.63 page 7
2.72 page 8
2.72 page 9
2.72 page 10
2.82 page 11
2.82 page 12
2.86 page 13
2.86 page 14
2.86 page 15
2.86 page 16
2.86 page 17
2.86 page 18
2.86 page 19
2.86 page 20
2.86 page 21
3.10 page 22
3.10 page 23
3.10 page 24
3.10 page 25
3.10 page 26
3.44 page 27
3.44 page 28
3.44 page 29
3.44 page 30
4.32 page 31
4.32 page 32
4.77 page 33
4.77 page 34
4.77 page 35
4.77 page 36
4.80 page 37

real    0m4.910s
user    0m0.069s
sys 0m0.005s
```

См. также [Throughput differences when using coroutines vs threading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9252020).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** написал этот ответ до того, как заметил решение лучше. Оставляю его пришедшим из поиска (вдруг найдет в нем кто что полезное).

---

Решил так:

```
from gevent.pool import Group
from gevent.queue import Queue
queue = Queue()

def handler(page_num):
    r = requests.get('sait.com?page={}'.format(page_num))
    if r.text != 'page not found':
        # суем все в очередь, потом ее будет разгребать другой обработчик
        queue.put_nowait(r)

def queue_handler():
    # ничего умнее я не придумал, кроме как усыпить обработчик на время обработки
    # одной страницы
    gevent.sleep(1)
    while not pages_queue.empty():
        data = queue.get()
        # работаем с данными
    # если очередь пустая, то все валидные (по нашим меркам) страницы уже закончились
    # и можно прекратить запрашивать страницы у сервера
    handlers_group.kill()

handlers_group, workers_group = Group(), Group()

# создаем сразу 200 запросов, все равно на сервер они все не уйдут
for i in range(1, 201):
    handlers_group.add(gevent.spawn(handler, i))
workers_group.add(gevent.spawn(queue_handler))

handlers_group.join()
workers_group.join()
```

Возможно, так себе решение, но это вроде бы лучше, чем выбросить gevent, учитывая что на нем уже держатся некоторые вещи в проекте. Если кто видит пути улучшения - пишите, буду благодарен.